# css changes not shown in browser

Tags: html, css, class, css-selectors

I don't think this is worthy question or not but still I am in trouble to find solution?

I am working on my first project in PHP and using the notepad++ editor. So, my problem is when ever I am saving my work and after restarting my laptop other changes were done in my website (which I didn't do).

One more thing changes on padding or margin in file don't shown on browser's console or on website.

What is the solution behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you made changes in the style section or main.css, those can be overwritten and not take effect if you also put styles within the html element.   Put some code up and people can help you better.

if you use the ``` code can go in your original post. Edit it.

PHP

```
<?php
$t=time();
echo($t . "<br>");
echo(date("Y-m-d",$t));
?>
```

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
```

CSS

```
code .c { /*max-width: 100px; margin: auto; padding-left: 35px; padding-right: 45px;*/ background-image: url(a.jpg); }
console .c { max-width: 1200px; margin: auto; padding-left: 35px; padding-right: 45px; background-image: url(a.jpg); }
```

Comment: this is css file code
.c
{
 /*max-width: 100px;
 margin: auto;
 padding-left: 35px;
 padding-right: 45px;*/ 
 background-image: url(a.jpg);
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">in browser's console
.c
{
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: auto;
 padding-left: 35px;
 padding-right: 45px; 
 background-image: url(a.jpg);
} i had linked only one css file. is it inaf?

Comment: one more thing in the code which shown in browser this i done previously so that's mean that browser is not updating the file ? but what to do

Comment: when you add comments/replies or edit your original post: put 3 ``` (key left of the 1 key) of those before your code...and 3 after your code.  It displays the code like Sadegh did above.   Then you can use normal text for descriptions before or after those ``` marks.   Put your CSS code in between those marks.  Then add your HTML code between marks, so people can help you easier.

Comment: whatever is in between the ```  /* ```   and  ```  */ ``` is just a comment and will not execute.  If you want those styles to take effect, remove the ```/*``` and the ```*/```

Answer (score 1):

1. Path to the stylesheet from root folder

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
```

2. You could add some variable to the end of href, such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/yourStyles.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```

Change version=1 to version=2 and so on after making some changes to the file content.

Comment: what is this echo time() ?

Comment: ```<?php
$t=time();
echo($t . "<br>");
echo(date("Y-m-d",$t));
?> '''  That should be in the PHP section and not in your style link

Comment: @harshalohana That will add the current timestamp on the end of a file path, so it will always be unique and never loaded from cache.